# JavaMailSender error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, email

I trying to send mail but today , gmail disable allow less secure apps and I can't send mail with JavaMailSender. Help me pls!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzmaS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ns0n.png)

Comment: Have you tried an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) instead?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask]. Did you follow the instructions gmail points you to?

Answer (score 0):

Use a secure SMTP Port, not Port 25

Few handy links to get you going;

- https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en